# PyOTA for beginners

Tags: documentation, pyota

I'm writing a thesis on IOTA and I wanna develop a simple application in Python as a related project
I have a very small amount of time to do it, so if u wanna be so kind to give me some useful links I would really appreciate it, guys!

I already found something for beginners but with very small amount of informations

My purpose is to develop an app which can make transactions with a related GUI

Also, I wanted to ask you if it's better to test it on the mainnet/on a public testnet/on a private testnet.

Comment: Please detail what problem you're looking to solve. General requests for links is not what Stack Exchange does well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know IOTA and develop an IOTA application in Python you can surely start with:

- [IOTA Developer Hub](https://iota.readme.io/)
- [PyOTA: The IOTA Python API Library](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py)
- [Pyota Docs](https://pyota.readthedocs.io)